# Making dll in assembler in VS 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, dll

When I try to make a dll files i got error:

```
1>asselib.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol MyProc
1>C:\Users\el bandito\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\testy\asselib\Debug\asselib.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

How project looks like:

-I selected new project -> win32 project -> DLL, export symbols

-sourcefile -> add new item -> asselib.asm

```
.486
.model flat, stdcall
.code

MyProc proc x: DWORD, y: DWORD
ret
MyProc endp
end
```

-sourcefile -> add new item -> asselib.def

```
LIBRARY "asselib"
EXPORTS
MyProc
```

-project -> build customization -> masm

-project -> properties -> linker -> input -> Module Def File, asselib.def

Comment: I'm not on assembler any more, but this may be a name mangling problem. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Comment: BTW, I've just noticed MyProc1 in the EXPORTS section. Is it a typo or a real error?

Answer (score 0):

I recall you have to explicitly declare the procedure as external.

```
PUBLIC MyProc
MyProc proc x: DWORD, y: DWORD
ret 8
MyProc endp
```

Also, the stdcall convention assumes callee cleans the stack. That means `ret 8` instead of `ret`.

Comment: didn't helped, but I tried my friends version of mine and his worked, when I change mine name.vcxproj for his, everythink is fine, but I need to know how to do it myself

Comment: Try changing function name to `MyProc@8`, and/or prepending with _.

Comment: its 'solved' i just make new project and do same thinks as i wrote before, and now it is working, i don't know where was the problem